# Запрет на добавление данных в бд(Spring)

Tags: java, postgresql, spring

Работало все хорошо, но после добавления Spring Security начали вылетать
Whitelabel Error Page.
There was an unexpected error (type=Forbidden, status=403).
Forbidden
при попытке добавить данные в бд.

```
//репозиторий добавления
import com.WebKurs.demo.Entity.Usr;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface UsrRepo extends JpaRepository<Usr, Long> {
    Usr findByUsername(String username);
}
```

```
//Метод в котором добавляется новая запись
    @PostMapping("/vacancy/add")
    public String addVacancy(
            @RequestParam String name,
            @RequestParam String shortDescription,
            @RequestParam String fullDescription,
            @RequestParam BigDecimal price,
            Model model){
        Vacancy vacancy = new Vacancy(name, shortDescription, fullDescription, price);
        jobRepo.save(vacancy);
        return "redirect:/";
    }
```

//SecurityInitializer

```
import org.springframework.security.web.context.AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer;

public class SecurityInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

}
```

```
//WebSecurityConfig
```

```
import com.WebKurs.demo.security.AuthProviderImpl;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthProviderImpl authProvider;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/login","/registration").anonymous()
                .and()
                    .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .loginProcessingUrl("/login/process")
                .and()
                    .logout();
    }

}
```

```
//WebAppInitializer

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class WebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{
                WebSecurityConfig.class
        };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[0];
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] {"/"};
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

добавить csrf token или отключить csrf

Класс WebSecurityConfig в методе configure добавил .and().csrf().disable()

Comment: Перенёс из комментария, на будущее: вы можете и сами это сделать, нажав "править" под ответом.